# How to check GPS permission is on or off for specific our application in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps

with the use of
    BOOL locaService=[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];

it will return boolean value for general GPS service, How can we check the service is on or off for specific our application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` returns a `CLAuthorizationStatus` which is typedef'd to be `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined, kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted, kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,` or `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`.

`kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` means you can use the GPS, and anything else means you can't.

(`kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` means they have disallowed you, `kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted` means you can't due to parental controls,  `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` means that the user has not yet responded to the "Allow this app to see my location?" prompt.)

Answer (score 1):

Check [authorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW11) in CLLocationManager.

> authorizationStatus
>
> Returns the application’s authorization status for using location
>   services.
>   + (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus